# What is difference between my atoi() calls?

Tags: c++, atoi

I have a big number stored in a string and try to extract a single digit. But what are the differences between those calls?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string bigNumber = "93485720394857230";
    char tmp = bigNumber.at(5);
    int digit = atoi(&tmp);
    int digit2 = atoi(&bigNumber.at(5))
    int digit3 = atoi(&bigNumber.at(12));
    std::cout << "digit: " << digit << std::endl;
    std::cout << "digit2: " << digit2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "digit3: " << digit3 << std::endl;
}
```

This will produce the following output.

> digit: 7
>
> digit2: 2147483647
>
> digit3: 57230

The first one is the desired result. The second one seems to me to be a random number, which I cannot find in the string. The third one is the end of the string, but not just a single digit as I expected, but up from the 12th index to the end of the string. Can somebody explain the different outputs to me?

EDIT: Would this be an acceptable solution?

```
char tmp[2] = {bigNumber.at(5), '\0'};
int digit = atoi(tmp);
std::cout << "digit: " << digit << std::endl;
```

Comment: Well, I was actually trying to solve the problem 8 of the Euler Project. I am already done for this semester :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all more or less explicable.

```
int main(){
    std::string bigNumber = "93485720394857230";
```

This line copies the single character '5' into the character variable. <strike>`atoi` will convert this correctly.</strike> `atoi` expects that the string parameter is a valid 0 terminated string. `&tmp` is only a pointer to the character variable - the behaviour of this call is undefined since the memory immediately following the character in memory is unknown. To be exact, you would have to create a null terminated string and pass that in.*

```
    char tmp = bigNumber.at(5);
    int digit = atoi(&tmp);
```

This line gets a pointer to the character in position 5 in the string. This happens to be a pointer into the original big number string above - so the string parameter to `atoi` looks like the string "5720394857230". `atoi` will clearly oveflow trying to turn this into an integer since no 32 bit integer will hold this.

```
    int digit2 = atoi(&bigNumber.at(5))
```

This line gets a pointer into the string at position 12. The parameter to `atoi` is the string 
"57230". This is converted into the integer 57230 correctly.

```
    int digit3 = atoi(&bigNumber.at(12));
```

...
    }

Since you are using C++, there are nicer methods to convert strings of characters into integers. One that I am partial to is the Boost lexical_cast library. You would use it like this:

```
char tmp = bigNumber.at(5);
// convert the character to a string then to an integer
int digit = boost::lexical_cast<int>(std::string(tmp));

// this copies the whole target string at position 5 and then attempts conversion
// if the conversion fails, then a bad_lexical_cast is thrown
int digit2=boost::lexical_cast<int>(std::string(bigNumber.at(5)));
```

* Strictly, `atoi` will scan through the numeric characters until a non-numeric one is found. It is clearly undefined when it would find one and what it will do when reading over invalid memory locations.

Comment: Thank you for this fancy solution. Is using lexical_cast safer than using atoi() or why do you suggest to use it?

Comment: lexical_cast is a lot safer because it takes advantage of modern C++ idioms to give type safety. You specify the target and source types (the source is inferred in the code above) - it will check for errors along the way and throw exceptions in the case if it was unable to perform the conversion. atoi is an older style API from the C standard library. lexical_cast has additional advantages in that it can work with many more defined types (including your own defined types and classes)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think you need to at the size of the string in your string constructor, so "string ( size_t n, char c );" can be called. I now use:
int digit=boost::lexical_cast<int>(std::string(1, bigNumber.at(5)));

Comment: Or digit=boost::lexical_cast<int>(std::string(&bigNumber.at(5),1)); to call string ( const char * s, size_t n ).

Comment: Please be aware that boost::lexical_cast is much slower as atoi. I also use it very often in a performance non-critical code. The problem with lexical_cast is that it uses stringstream for conversion. If you are working in a multi-threaded environement any stream class from the standard lib will use locks on a mutex for every character being inserted, even if the stream object is used from a single thread.Your number consisting of 17 chars will involve 17 mutex locks when put into stream.

Comment: That's good to know. However, I think that you should generally favour obviously correct code over more risky (but performant) alternatives unless you are sure you are running in the critical path for performance - therefore I would recommend using streams, type safety, lexical cast and that kind of thing by default

Answer (score 5):

I know why the 2nd number is displayed.

[From the atoi reference.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

> If the correct value is out of the range of representable values, **`INT_MAX`** or INT_MIN is returned.

2147483647 is INT_MAX

Answer (score 3):

`bigNumber.at()` doesn't return a new string with a single character but the address of a character in the string. So the second call is actually:

```
atoi("720394857230")
```

which causes the internal algorithm to overflow.

Also, the first call is very dangerous since it depends on the (random) value in memory at `(&tmp)+1`.

You have to allocate a string with two characters, assign the single character from `bigNumber.at()` to the first and `\0` to the second and then call `atoi()` with the address of the temporary string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Does this mean, that my first solution only works, because I have "\0" by chance in my memory after &tmp?

Comment: atoi() will stop on any non-numeric character, so you have a chance of 96% (245 to 10) that it works.

Answer (score 3):

The argument to `atoi` should be a zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 3):

Function `at` gives pointer to char in the string. Function `atoi` converts string to int, not only one char.