# When do c++ stream objects use mutexes?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, iostream

In the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026190/what-is-difference-between-my-atoi-calls/1026212#1026212) ovanes states:

> Please be aware that
>   boost::lexical_cast is much slower as
>   atoi. I also use it very often in a
>   performance non-critical code. The
>   problem with lexical_cast is that it
>   uses stringstream for conversion. If
>   you are working in a multi-threaded
>   environement any stream class from the
>   standard lib will use locks on a mutex
>   for every character being inserted,
>   even if the stream object is used from
>   a single thread.Your number consisting
>   of 17 chars will involve 17 mutex
>   locks when put into stream. – ovanes
>   Jun 22 at 11:59

Which begs the question, when do `<iostream>` objects lock a mutex? Is this true for objects from `<sstream>` as well? If so can this be prevented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current C++ standard (C++03) does not contain anything about multi-threading.

Because of this, how a library uses mutexes would depend on the specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with string_stream is that it is quite heavy. And it is not related to Mutexes.

And I'll explain why:

- stringstream uses generic interface to access underlying buffer, same as used for files or for console access: a set of virtual functions. It is slower then iterating over `char *`
- it Uses locale information so you may actually parse string that depends on type of thousands separators or different types of digits that are fetched for other class in locale interface.
- And finally it calls atoi to convert the string to number.

`lexical_cast` is very powerful because it allows to cast any value and not integer only as done with `atoi` but with power comes prices.

Second thing, I don't think that any string_buffer implementation uses mutexes. File stream has sense in it but not string stream.